# Sign of some permutation.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, alternative-proof

I trying to find the sign of this permutation:

$\left(\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & n-1 & n\\
2 & 4 & 6 & \cdots & 1 & 3 & 5 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots
 \end{array}\right)$

I think that, I resolved that by counting inversions. If $n=10$ then we have $1$ cycle with length 10, so sign of permutation is equal $(-1)^{10-1}=-1$.

$\left(\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9
 \end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cccccccccc}1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 & 9 & 7 & 3 & 6 \end{array}\right)$

If I'd like to count inversions then I have this table

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
(2,1)\\
(4,1) & (4,3)\\
(6,1) & (6,3) & (6,5)\\
(8,1) & (8,3) & (8,5) & (8,7)\\
(10,1) & (10,3) & (10,5) & (10,7) & (10,9)
\end{array}$

There is $\sum_{i=1}^{5}i=\frac{6\cdot 5}{2}=15$ inversions and sign of permutation is equal again $(-1)^{15}=-1$.

For generalized form and even $n$ the last of row in this table has form:

$(n,1)(n,3),\cdots,(n,n-1)$

Quantity of braces is equal $\frac{n}{2}$. Now we can count inversions

$\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}i=\frac{\left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right)\frac{n}{2}}{2}=\frac{(n+2)n}{8}$

If $n$ is odd, then end of permutation has column $\begin{array}{c}n\\n\end{array}$. This is cycle with length $1$ and we can consider permutation of $n-1$ elements, then $n-1$ is even.

Finally my result is

$\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}=\frac{\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}{2}$

and sign of permutation is equal $(-1)^{\frac{\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}{2}}$.

Exercise is founded in A.I.Kostrikin's book where result is $(-1)^{\frac{n+2}{2}}$. Is my result or result from book proper? And how can I resolve that without counting inversions? Only finding decomposition into disjoint cycles?

---

Calculated values for $2\le n\le 101$. It seems that my formula is working. But I have still question about another way to achieve this result.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & sign & \frac{\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}{2} & n & sign & \frac{\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}{2}\\
\hline
2 & -1 & 1 & 52 & -1 & 351\\
3 & -1 & 1 & 53 & -1 & 351\\
4 & -1 & 3 & 54 & 1 & 378\\
5 & -1 & 3 & 55 & 1 & 378\\
6 & 1 & 6 & 56 & 1 & 406\\
7 & 1 & 6 & 57 & 1 & 406\\
8 & 1 & 10 & 58 & -1 & 435\\
9 & 1 & 10 & 59 & -1 & 435\\
10 & -1 & 15 & 60 & -1 & 465\\
11 & -1 & 15 & 61 & -1 & 465\\
12 & -1 & 21 & 62 & 1 & 496\\
13 & -1 & 21 & 63 & 1 & 496\\
14 & 1 & 28 & 64 & 1 & 528\\
15 & 1 & 28 & 65 & 1 & 528\\
16 & 1 & 36 & 66 & -1 & 561\\
17 & 1 & 36 & 67 & -1 & 561\\
18 & -1 & 45 & 68 & -1 & 595\\
19 & -1 & 45 & 69 & -1 & 595\\
20 & -1 & 55 & 70 & 1 & 630\\
21 & -1 & 55 & 71 & 1 & 630\\
22 & 1 & 66 & 72 & 1 & 666\\
23 & 1 & 66 & 73 & 1 & 666\\
24 & 1 & 78 & 74 & -1 & 703\\
25 & 1 & 78 & 75 & -1 & 703\\
26 & -1 & 91 & 76 & -1 & 741\\
27 & -1 & 91 & 77 & -1 & 741\\
28 & -1 & 105 & 78 & 1 & 780\\
29 & -1 & 105 & 79 & 1 & 780\\
30 & 1 & 120 & 80 & 1 & 820\\
31 & 1 & 120 & 81 & 1 & 820\\
32 & 1 & 136 & 82 & -1 & 861\\
33 & 1 & 136 & 83 & -1 & 861\\
34 & -1 & 153 & 84 & -1 & 903\\
35 & -1 & 153 & 85 & -1 & 903\\
36 & -1 & 171 & 86 & 1 & 946\\
37 & -1 & 171 & 87 & 1 & 946\\
38 & 1 & 190 & 88 & 1 & 990\\
39 & 1 & 190 & 89 & 1 & 990\\
40 & 1 & 210 & 90 & -1 & 1035\\
41 & 1 & 210 & 91 & -1 & 1035\\
42 & -1 & 231 & 92 & -1 & 1081\\
43 & -1 & 231 & 93 & -1 & 1081\\
44 & -1 & 253 & 94 & 1 & 1128\\
45 & -1 & 253 & 95 & 1 & 1128\\
46 & 1 & 276 & 96 & 1 & 1176\\
47 & 1 & 276 & 97 & 1 & 1176\\
48 & 1 & 300 & 98 & -1 & 1225\\
49 & 1 & 300 & 99 & -1 & 1225\\
50 & -1 & 325 & 100 & -1 & 1275\\
51 & -1 & 325 & 101 & -1 & 1275\\
\hline
\end{array}$

Comment: $\frac{n+2}2$ isn't always an integer, so I doubt the given result is true (unless it is for even $n$ only). Also, you should negate your answer for odd $n$.

Comment: For odd $n$ I tried it too. $\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 5\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 2 & 4 & 3\end{array}\right)(5)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\2 & 4 & 1 & 3\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 2 & 4 & 3\end{array}\right)$ so sign of permutation when $n=5$ and $n=4$ is that same. It is true for all odd $n$ because always there will by cycle with length 1. $\left\lfloor\frac{5}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{4}{2}\right\rfloor=2$.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that the sign of the permutation is the **opposite** of the cycle length, so for odd $n$, you get the same as for $n-1$ indeed. But that doesn't explain the answer your book gives. (i.e., that it may not be a real number)

Comment: Answer is at the end of the book and it is set of exercises, so I think that there is typo in answer. That's why I'm looking for another way to find result.

Comment: You could calculate it for all even $n$ up to $12$ or so and compare the outcomes. Probably it is periodic with period $4$ or $8$, so if $8$ consecutive answers match, your formula is prabably right.